# Mongoose query parent and include children with reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 Mongoose Schemas. Location and Place. I need to be able to pull location information when I query place and it works well with populate. However in another case, I need to find all places that belong to location.

Does this mean that I need to reference Places in Location Schema as well? Multiple places can belong to single location. I can't embed places in location because places will have sub information, and I don't want locations document get too big cause of that.

```
var LocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
}); 

var PlaceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  location: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Location'},
  type: String,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to query by the location id.

```
Places.find({location: { $in: [location ids] }}).then(places => {...})
```

Comment: Not sure if I like this approach, it gets messy when I have array of locations and I need to get their places.

Comment: {$in: <array>} would return all places with ids that are in an array of locations.